# (Closed) Swift - UICollectionView Context Menu Row

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am currently implementing a UICollectionView to display CoreData data in my application, I want to add the "delete" function for each cell using a ContextMenu.

On the internet I have observed many pages to be able to customize the UIMenuController in the cells of a UITableView and UICollectionView but I still can not display my MenuItem "delete".

This is my code:

```
private func config_menu()
{
    let menuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(test(_:)))
    let menu = UIMenuController.shared
    menu.menuItems = [menuItem]
    menu.update()
}

@objc func test(_ sender: Any?)
{

}
```

CollectionView:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if (action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(test(_:)))
        {
            return true
        }
        return false
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
       print("Hello world")
   }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :D to be able to use custom MenuItems it is necessary to declare them in the subclass of the cell, in this way::

```
class Cell_Prueba: UICollectionViewCell {


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return (action == #selector(test(_:)))
    }

    @objc func test(_ sender: Any?)
    {
        //Do Any
    }
}
```